# How to write if statement in JSON?

Tags: arrays, json

I don't know json , I have for loop statement.I need only single data  , How can write if statement in JSON. Please help me,

```
function myFunction(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(response);
        var i;
        var out = "<table>";    
       for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            out += "<tr><td> " +
            arr[i].offerPercentage +
            "</td><td>" +
            arr[i].offerName +      
            "</td></tr>";
        }enter code here
        out += "</table>";
        document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean. JSON is a file format, not a programming language, so an if statement in JSON has no obvious meaning. (Oh, and `arr[0]` should probably be `arr[i]`)

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Could you add some context as to where you want to add the if statement and what's the exact purpose? JSON is not a language. JSON is how you represent objects in javascript, though it is widely used as a storage format. The code you posted seems like javascript code.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

**Edit:**
Now that it's clear what you want, to loop over just a single item, you change the amount of times to iterate - currently it will iterate over the whole array, to only iterate over one change `arr.length` to `1` (or however many items you want to display):

```
function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "<table>";    

    for(i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        out += "<tr><td> " +
        arr[0].offerPercentage +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[0].offerName +      
        "</td></tr>";
    }

    out += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

or you could simply reference the first result directly and bypass the loop which would make more sense:

```
function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "<table>";

    // Only append if `arr` has at least one result.
    if (typeof arr[0] !== 'undefined') {
        out += "<tr><td> " + 
        arr[0].offerPercentage +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[0].offerName +      
        "</td></tr>";
    }

    out += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

**Old Answer:**
Objects in Javascript don't have a `.length` property.

To loop over an object, use the [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) syntax:

```
for (var offer in arr) {
    // `offer.offerPercentage` and `offer.offerName` will be available here.
}
```

If what's being returned *is* actually an array, your issue isn't your syntax, it's the fact that you are using `arr[0]` in each loop rather than `arr[i]`.

Comment: `arr.length` works fine in plain javascript, provided that the json being parsed is an array. Please double check before posting. Your answers could be misleading.

Comment: Sorry @AnkitKhettry but you're wrong. Please re-read my answer before saying I'm wrong?

Comment: `var a = '[{"First_name": "Allan","Last_name": "Hernandez","Date_of_birth": "1981-01-19","Height": 178},{"First_name": "Harley","Last_name": "Smith","Date_of_birth": "1988-05-21","Height": 185}]';` This is a valid json. length property works for this. It has never been mentioned in the question whether the json being parsed is not an array. Infact, from the code in question, it is pretty apparent that the json being parsed _IS_ an array. As I said, your answer could be misleading.

Comment: i changed arr[i], i got more data display,but i want only single data only display

Comment: You've edited your original reply to me with the addition of 'provided the json being parsed is an array'.

It's also not apparent that the response being returned is an array. The question asks about looping over 'JSON'. No mention of array. Nor object.

Comment: By single data do you mean the first item in the array??

Comment: Objects in JavaScript DO have a length property; iteration over a single object in a collection is meaningless. This answer doesn't provide anything useful. -1 here

Comment: Look, I've updated my answer based on responses. My answer is correct whichever way you look at it. I agree that looping through an array for only one iteration is meaningless, however I've provided an explanation on how his loop is working and a more 'meaningful' answer below.

And a JSON object parsed with `JSON.parse()` will absolutely not have a `length` proeprty.

Comment: no data display,error show Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: missed an opening bracket, try again :)